# "Самый лучший" — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто можно услышать выражение "самый лучший", оно прочно вошло в нашу речь. Но разве это грамотно? Если "лучший", то и так "самый".

Comment: Сейчас очень популярно составлять списки: "10 лучших книг о кулинарии", "25 лучших сказок для детей" и т.д. Естественно что в списке лучших что-то может быть "еще более лучшим".

Comment: А может так быть, что "лучший" - это не превосходная степень, а сравнительная?  Тогда "самый лучший" как раз и превосходная степень...

Answer (score 5):

Это нормально. Вне математики, на бытовом уровне "просто лучший" - еще не самый, не наилучший.

UPD

Я понял, что моей четырехлетней давности реплики явно недостаточно для понимания. 
Уточняю. "Лучший" - это не только превосходная степень, это еще и сравнительная ("лучший чем"). Причем превосходная - как раз в последнюю очередь. Поэтому "самый лучший" - вполне нормально.

Вообще тут есть интересный момент. Когда-то когда-то все современные формы превосходной степени прилагательных были именно сравнительными степенями. С развитием грамматики они стали употребляться для превосходной степени:  сначала наряду со сравнительной, а потом исключительно. Сравнительная же степень стала употребляться почти исключительно в краткой форме - и в предикативе: "Это яблоко краснее (чем то)".

Но сохранились четыре прилагательных, сохранившие полные формы сравнительной степени: *больший, меньший, лучший и худший*. Причем три последние омонимичны тем же прилагательным превосходной степени. Естественно, они имеют право иметь "самый" перед собой - для выражения аналитической формы превосходной степени.

Итак, "исключения" (если так можно назвать) как минимум три: *самый лучший, самый худший и самый меньший*.

UPD2

> ```
> *Мы получали порцион лучший, чем на военных судах.*
> ```

А. С. Грин. Бегущая по волнам (1926)

Если кто-то покажет мне учебник, что здесь ***не сравнительная степень***, буду весьма удивлен. Примеров таких до черта, но взял из несомненно авторитетного.

(+)---

Фу, нашел "учебник".

Ю. Князев, Грамматическая семантика. Русский язык в типологической перспективе.

[Учебник](https://books.google.ru/books?id=hWjMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=nrXMzAyhBs&sig=w06BUUDTFgVPm3oGzfDVwY97teU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi21bDny4bNAhXBBSwKHVh7Cj8Q6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень интересно. А тогда " лучше" - эта какая форма? Наверное, положительная! самый лучший - это плеоназм. Хотите вы того или нет. Просто плеоназм этот уже в разговорной речи допускается.

Comment: И да, буду благодарен, если вы потрудитесь показать мне учебник, где будет написано, что "лучший" - это и сравнительная степень и превосходная степень.

Comment: @Серж *А тогда " лучше" - эта какая форма?* - это тоже сравнительная степень, основная, на неё никто не покушался.

Comment: @Серж *И да, буду благодарен, если вы потрудитесь* - посылать читать учебники - это ваша прерогатива. У меня в ответе специально для вас - ссылка на вполне академическую литературу.

Comment: @Серж *самый лучший - это плеоназм. Хотите вы того или нет.* -  а вот это уже, простите, выходит за рамки моего понимания приличий. В дальнейшем, простите, буду игнорировать вместе с остальной частью ваших комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

«Он никак не в состоянии был понять, чего фрау Леноре так убивается, и в сердце своем он тут же решил, что женщины, даже самые лучшие, страдают отсутствием сообразительной способности!» Тургенев. Вешние воды.

Comment: *Самые лучшие* — это перебор. Самый лучший один, а не несколько.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что лучших может быть несколько:
*Эти ребята лучшие в стрельбе. А Бен — самый лучший (наилучший) из них.*

Есть же выражение "лучший из лучших" (= "наилучший"/"самый лучший").

Мне кажется, что иногда "самый лучший" допустимо. Наверно, разговорный вариант.

Возьмём такой пример:
*Ты самый лучший брат на свете.* || Здесь просто "лучший" не звучит.

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший - плеоназм. Лучший - это превосходная степень. В нем уже содержится "самый".

Comment: Если "лучший" - превосходная степень, то какая - сравнительная?

Comment: @VictorBazarov *Лучший, меньший и худший* - одновременно превосходные и сравнительные степени соответствующих прилагательных. Подробности - см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Так говорить нельзя. В книге «Звоним русисту» (Юлия Матийченко — автор) сказано, что это действительно плеоназм. А кто-нибудь помнит «Самый лучший фильм»? :) И тут ошиблись, выходит. Вообще говоря, в бытовой беседе я бы мог себе позволить так сказать, ибо при речевом потоке и не такое встретишь.

Comment: А кто эта барышня, что я ей должен верить?

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно недопустимо использовать одновременно два способа выражения сравнения: слова более/менее или самый/наиболее в сочетании с прилагательным в сравнительной или превосходной степени! Но САМЫЙ ЛУЧШИЙ это исключение из правила.
В институте нам говорили, что и "самый лучший" использовать нельзя, но НОРМА понятие гибкое и постоянно меняющееся, и теперь, видимо, современный язык допускает использование такого словосочетания.

http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/775-23_imya_prilagatelnoe.html

Comment: Да в общем-то никто и не утверждает, что "самый лучший" - ошибка. Но вот источник ваш - это какая пародия на учебник. Крайне непрофессиональное изложение. Меняющаяся норма  - тут ну совсем "не при делах", наоборот, тут сохранение исторического значения. И что это за институт, где вам такое твердили? Вы не наговариваете?

Comment: Зачем в перечислении «слова более/менее или самый/наиболее» использовать математические символы?